# Add QPushButton into exist QTableWidget - Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

[image]

Hi,
I have the following QTableWidget which already is updated with data from dataframe.
I am using 2 "for" loops to fill it up, one for row and one for cols.
Trying to add to each row in the 1st (before col **"X"**) QPushButton that will pop a new window for future propose.

```
for j in range(self.tablewidget.columnCount()):
for i in range(self.tablewidget.rowCount()):
    self.push_btn = QPushButton()
    self.tablewidget.cellWidget(i,j)
    self.tablewidget.setCellWidget(i, 0, self.push_btn )
```

With this, the app gets stuck until crashes without any info.

Thanks alot!

Comment: (1) Remove `self.tablewidget.cellWidget(i,j)`, which is pointless. (2) Move the column-loop to inside the row-loop and *after* the other two lines. Any code that requires both the row and column should go inside the column-loop; code that only requires the row should go inside the row-loop.

Comment: same results, app is not responding and crash when setCellWidget being called.  I do set the col and row size and putting data from df, but unable to add any widget which is not QTableWidgetItem
self.tablewidget.setColumnCount(nColumns)
self.tablewidget.setRowCount(nRows)

Comment: @PhilpK, I tried to reproduce your example on my PC. There was no crash. The buttons were inserted inside all first column rows with no problem. Are you sure this is the piece of code that makes your application freeze and crash? Try providing more of your app's script on your post. You don't need to include *all of it*, just the necessary so we can reproduce the example and understand what's really crashing the application.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it, the issue was with Qrunnable threads, my method for inserting setCellWidget didn't wait until the finished signal.

Thanks!